# How to speed up frame rates in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, real-time, image-recognition

## The question itself.

I'm currently developing a real-time image recognition software with MATLAB, and I'm having some trouble trying to speed up the frame rates with my webcam. Even when I process only a fraction of the image (using a ROI to crop it) it doesn't speed up the frame rate by much.

That lead me to believe that my computations in every frame (or the size of them, to be more specific) aren't the problem. So, looking for an answer, I made the simple code:

```
imaqreset;

% Turn the webcam on with a MJPG_6480x480 acquisition format.
webcam1 = videoinput('winvideo',1,'MJPG_640x480');
set(webcam1,'FramesPerTrigger',1);
set(webcam1,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
triggerconfig(webcam1,'Manual');
start(webcam1);

% Pre-allocate for the variable wich will hold the frame rates over time.
a = zeros(1,100)';

% Acquire frames in a loop and saves the frame rate in each iteration.
for i=1:100

    % Starts the timer.
    tic;

    % Triggers the webcam1 to capture a frame.
    trigger(webcam1);

    % Saves the frame in a dummy variable (just to simulate the acquisition time)
    i1 = getdata(webcam1,1);

    % The frame rate for this iteration will 1/(time for iteration).
    a(i) = 1/toc;    
end

% Plots the frame rates over time.
plot(a);

% Cleans up.
delete(webcam1);
```

In my computer this code runs somewhat stable around 12.4 fps. Now, the tricky part is this: the code runs with the same frame rate if I change the acquisition format to 'MJPG_160x120'! or to 'MJPG_1280_1024'!!

Does this mean that no matter the size of the image MATLAB needs to acquire from the webcam, the fastest frame rate I will be able to achieve in this computer, with this webcam is ~12.4fps? Or am I missing something?

## One last thing...

In my software (that is, not the simplified code posted above, but my real code, which process each frame) the frame rate drops to something about 7 fps when processing the whole frame, but when the computer finds the target (and hence, narrows the search using a ROI) the frame rate climbs back to about 12 fps (not higher, as I would expect). For me this is somewhat good evidence that the max frame rate is not being dictated by my code, but by the image acquisition speed.

---

Any help would be appreciated, thank's in advance!

Comment: Isn't the frame rate based on the your webcam hardware?

Comment: I believe it's maximum value is dictated by the hardware. But in other applications I can get ~30fps with this camera, so that tells me its something with matlab and the way I'm acquiring the data.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the question in the link solves a performance issue when a real time preview is used together with getsnapshot, which is not relevant for this question.